# Most frequent element in a string array, MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string array, for instance:

```
arr = ['hello'; 'world'; 'hello'; 'again'; 'I----'; 'said-'; 'hello'; 'again']
```

How can I extract the most frequent string, which is `'hello'` in this example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First step, use a cell array rather than string array:

```
arr = {'hello', 'world'; 'hello', 'again'; 'I----', 'said-'; 'hello', 'again'};
```

Second, use unique to get the unique strings (this doesn't work on a string array, which is why I suggest the cell):

```
[unique_strings, ~, string_map]=unique(arr);
```

Then use mode on the string_map variable to find the most common values:

```
most_common_string=unique_strings(mode(string_map));
```

Comment: +1: but there's no need for cell arrays. You can use `unique(arr, 'rows')`.

Comment: Oh great, thanks! I don't use them very often, didn't know this function.

Comment: Just a note about string arrays and the above comment: in this instance, the string would need to be reformatted so that each string was a separate row, rather than trying to have two strings on a single line - this only works as a cell, otherwise Matlab considers the whole line a single concatenated string, i.e. the initial `arr` in the question is equivalent to `['helloworld','helloagain';,'I----said-';'helloagain']`

Comment: All strings in the question are concatenated vertically with a semicolon. I think you copy-pasted `arr` wrong.

Comment: Oh weird. Thanks. Don't know how that happened.

Comment: If the user wants the *string* output instead of a 1x1 cell array containing the string, then they should use `most_common_string=unique_strings{mode(string_map)};`

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use cell arrays and *regexp* function; the behavior of string arrays may not be what you expect.

```
arr = {'hello', 'world'; 'hello', 'again'; 'I----', 'said-'; 'hello', 'again'};
```

If you use

```
hellos = sum(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(arr, 'hello')));
```

it will return the number of `'hello'`'s in cell array `arr`.

Comment: -1: The question is about finding the most frequent string, not a specific predetermined string.

Comment: And even if you were looking for a specific string, `regexp` would be a bit overkill. `strcmp` can be used to identify equal strings in a cell array.